# BIOS doesn't recognize Linux drive/partition

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, bios, arch-linux

Today I bought a new SSD (Kingston SNV500G) specifically so I can install Archcraft on it without messing with Windows 11 partition.

I installed the distro and went to bios to switch the boot order but could not find the drive there.

I'm currently downloading Boot Repair ISO but I honestly don't want to make matters worse before asking for help.

This is what Disk Management on Windows 11 shows

[image]

I'm on Windows now and `bcdedit` returns the following

```
C:\Windows\System32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume6
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {114f7cac-3e08-11ed-8caf-e8c5e7eccbda}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 11
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {114f7caf-3e08-11ed-8caf-e8c5e7eccbda}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {114f7cac-3e08-11ed-8caf-e8c5e7eccbda}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
```

And "System Information" shows BIOS Mode: UEFI

I also installed Archcraft in UEFI

Edit: I rebooted and pressed F11 to boot from USB and I was presented with a Boot Menu that includes "Archcraft" selecting that took me the Archcraft boot menu that include Windows 11. So now I am able to select either Windows or Archcraft if I press F11.

EDIT 2: to clarify: I didn't solve the problem. I have to press F11 every time during boot to be able to select Archcraft. if I don't, the system boots into Windows 11 automatically and ignores the other boot loader. So obviously I can't keep pressing F11 every single time I boot my pc.

Comment: You mean that you boot from USB and not from the SSD? Perhaps you installed Archcraft on the wrong disk?

Comment: No, you misunderstood. I didn't say I installed or booted from USB, I said that I pressed F11 to boot from usb which had "Boot Repair ISO" and in doing so I was presented with a boot menu that included Archcraft.

Comment: You should remove the answer for your question and submit an answer with enough details to be considered an answer

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't find a solution to the problem. I can't press F11 every time I turn on my PC. If I don't press F11 during boot, the system boots into Windows 11 and ignores Archcraft.

Comment: @Halnex - One problem I see is you have two EFI partitions instead of a single EFI partition that contains the entries for both Windows and Linux. With the original EFI partition being only 100 MB instead of normally is a much larger size I wouldn't try to merge your entries into that partition.

Comment: @Ramhound I had Windows 11 already installed as an EFI partition then I installed Archcraft as an EFI on another drive. So How can I rectify this error?

Comment: @Ramhound I fixed it. I tinkered around in BIOS and found a menu called "UEFI Boot Priorities" and there I selected the Arch partition as #1 instead of Windows and now I boot directly into Arch's boot menu and I can select either Arch or Windows. That menu item was hidden and I had to scroll down to see it.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed Archcraft on the second disk, but have not installed
the GRUB bootloader that allows multi-booting Linux and Windows.
You only have the old Windows bootloader, that only knows how to boot
Windows.

You need to install GRUB, or repeat the installation of Archcraft,
letting it install GRUB this time.
I don't know this distribution, so cannot guide you in the
required steps.

Or you can just continue on using the BIOS as your bootloader,
since it can find both boot instances.

Comment: When I press F11 and select Archcraft I'm presented with Archcraft's boot menu which includes both Windows and Archcraft. Is this not grub? Also can't install Grub from within Arch without having to reinstall the distro?

Comment: Yes, this seems like GRUB. The simplest solution then would be to set Archcraft in the BIOS as your default boot, meaning the new second disk rather than the first one. No other action would be required.

Comment: This is the problem, it's not appearing in BIOS. I press "DEL" to enter BIOS but F11 to boot from USB. Going into BIOS I don't see the drive/partition which I used to install Linux on.

Comment: I never saw a case like that, so I think there was some error during the installation of Archcraft. Repeating it while paying great attention to detail might be a solution.

Comment: I fixed it. I tinkered around in BIOS and found a menu called "UEFI Boot Priorities" and there I selected the Arch partition as #1 instead of Windows and now I boot directly into Arch's boot menu and I can select either Arch or Windows. That menu item was hidden and I had to scroll down to see it.

Comment: *"I tinkered around in BIOS and found a menu called "UEFI Boot Priorities"* and there I selected the Arch * Yes, this is what you should've done from the start and what everybody was telling you to do. Keep this in mind for the future: UEFI mode boots stanzas in the ESP (EFI System Partition), NOT drives/partitions like before with BIOS mode. And, of course, you don't have BIOS, you have UEFI, the firmware type that replaced BIOS more than a DECADE ago. If you're installing OSes and particularly setting up a multi-boot you must keep up with the technology.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your new drive is not enough quickly recognized by BIOS to make it able to boot from it. I have the same with other equipment. In result I start the computer, open boot menu, wait a moment and then make a soft-reset (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>) to again open boot menu and then the drive appears.

Also, you need to make Linux partition bootable (active) for BIOS so it could know that there is OS that can be booted. This is about MBR.

With GPT you would need mostly GRUB installed on the drive with Linux. Or other boot loader.

Comment: How does one make a linux partition bootable?

Comment: @Halnex you can use GParted for example to switch the "active" flag (flag as bootable).

Comment: I don't see any "active" flags: https://i.imgur.com/cvQa9aF.png

Comment: @Halnex here you have "boot" flag which should be checked. Active = boot.

Comment: The screenshot looks correct as is. That's a GPT disk with an EFI System Partition – GParted's "boot" flag means something completely different here (there is no active partition on EFI systems), and it should _not_ be set on the OS partition, only on the EFI System Partition as that's where the bootloader is actually located.